# Is there a Java IoC container that supports managing classloaders?

Tags: java, inversion-of-control, classloader, ioc-container

I'm looking for a somewhat lightweight IoC container that will also allow me to manage different classloaders with different classpaths. Then multiple versions of code could be run in the different classloaders/classpaths, but all managed together.

Comment: [tag:osgi] + [tag:spring-dm]?

Comment: @Tomasz Not sure I'd consider osgi "lightweight"

Comment: Right, I was assuming OSGI was not lightweight. Is there a way to do it lightweight?

Answer (score 1):

You may look at pico container http://picocontainer.org

Comment: I like picocontainer but I don't see anything about it managing containers in different classloaders with different classpaths.

Answer (score 1):

OSGi can be **very** lightweight, believe me!
I have seen it run on 8 MB RAM - [see here](http://www.prosyst.com/media/prosyst_media/img_news/World%C2%B4s%20smallest%20OSGi%20solution%20-%20Technical%20Paper.pdf)

Btw all the services are optional according to the spec, you can strip everything you don't need - that's the beauty of OSGi, it is incredibly modular.

The different classloaders are no problem of course, every bundle has its own classloader anyway; the dependencies can be controlled in detail using the syntax of the manifest.

If you want IoC and are not happy with the classical BundleActivator you can use OSGi Declarative Services - see in the OSGi spec under number 112.

Answer (score 0):

You can use weld or any other DI framework along with OSGI.

If you are writing a web app, then [jboss now supports OSGI](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/osgi) seemlessly and also provides WELD as well.